# Python: To find the website of a list of companies

Tags: python, python-requests, google-search

I tried using the below python code to find the websites of the companies. But after trying few times, I face a **Service Unavailable** error.

I have finished the first level of finding the possible domains of the companies. For example :

CompanyExample [u'http://www.examples.com/', u'https://www.example.com/quote/CGL:SP', u'http://example2.sgx.com/FileOpen/China%20Great%20Land.ashx?App=Prospectus&FileID=3813', u'https://www.example3.com/php/company-profile/SG/en_2036109.html']

```
from google import search
for link in links:
    parsed_uri = urlparse(link)
    domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
    for url in search(domain,stop = 4):
         print url
```

Kindly help me on:

1. Why do I find **urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable** error suddenly.
2. Is there any other method(Python requests) to find websites of the list of companies ?

Answer (score 0):

Google APIs usually are rate limited for non-paying users. Going over your limit is probably what causes the 503 responses. According to the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) you get 100 free searches per day, after that it's $5 per 1000 queries up to 10000 queries:

> Custom Search Engine (free)
>
> For CSE users, the API provides 100 search queries per day for free.
> If you need more, you may sign up for billing in the API Console.
> Additional requests cost $5 per 1000 queries, up to 10k queries per
> day.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kohl. Is there any other method I can use like python requests to search the websites ?

Comment: @NiviSRa The problem is that if you search too much, Google will temporarily blacklist your IP (which can also become a problem if you're behind some proxy server and it's not you who hit the limit), so you may be out of luck.

Comment: BTW, since you seem to be fairly new to SO, please make sure you take the tour to get most out of the site: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm new to this topic and I shall surely look into it.

Comment: @NiviSra: use google API key, ask friends yo create google API key so you can rotate the key for 100 searchs each keys

Comment: Oh thats interesting @PhongPhung. Sure I shall check.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **`"from urllib.parse import urlparse"`** insted of

> #import urlparse
> #import urllib2